# List With Row and Column : Type Error : list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Tags: python

`BS` is the list. I would like to add a `BS` List with rows and columns to define others places.

But i'm getting the error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuples

Do I need to change the `BS` datatype from something such as `Cell Array`, or `tuple`?

```
 BS = []
 BS.append([])
 value = max(ravel(BSpar))
 [r, c]= find(BSpar == value, nargout=2)
     for j in range(K):
        block = BS[r,c][i * Ksize:(i - 1) * Ksize, j * Ksize:(j + 1) * Ksize]
        Bblock[i].append(block)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ravel` is not defined, also your indents seem to be off.

Answer (score 0):

[i * Ksize:(i - 1) * Ksize, j * Ksize:(j + 1) * Ksize]

The above is of form `[A:B:C]` where:

A is `i * Ksize`

B is `(i - 1) * Ksize, j * Ksize`

C is `(j + 1) * Ksize`

B is where the problem is - there is a comma, which indicates it is a tuple of two numbers, but you are only allowed a single number there.